# This appears to be a class on a Javascript event. What is it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just ran across some jQuery that looks like this:

```
$('.add-row').live('click.add', function() { 
    // do something
}
```

This appears to be binding to the **'click.add'** event. I use custom events myself and think they're awesome, but doing `git grep` on our code base doesn't reveal any place where a custom event called `click.add` is triggered, and in any case, this behavior is triggered by a normal click. Nor do I see an `.add` class anywhere in the HTML.

I don't think you can have classes on Javascript events. Any idea what this odd bit of syntax is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a featured called [namespaced events](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events).  In this example, `add` is a namespace.  It is effectively a class for events, so that you can categorise them and handle/trigger them accordingly.  For instance, you might write a plugin and give every event handler a namespace of `myPlugin` so that you can unbind them without removing the user's other event handlers:

```
$('a').bind('click.myPlugin', function(){ /*...*/ }); // bind with the myPlugin namespace
$('a').bind('click'), function() { /* ... */ }); // bind without a namespace
$('a').unbind('.myPlugin'); // only removes the first function
```

This works for `trigger` as well.

Comment: Great example! I'm actually working on a jQuery plugin that could benefit from that technique. Thanks for showing not only what this is, but why one might use it.

Answer (score 7):

See http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/ and especially http://api.jquery.com/bind/:

> If the eventType string contains a
>   period (.) character, then the event
>   is namespaced. The period character
>   separates the event from its
>   namespace. For example, in the call
>   .bind('click.name', handler), the
>   string click is the event type, and
>   the string name is the namespace.
>   Namespacing allows us to unbind or
>   trigger some events of a type without
>   affecting others. See the discussion
>   of .unbind() for more information.